# read csv file from buffer got EmptyDataError?

Tags: pandas

i need to read a string like csv content with pandas , but pandas get some errors, i don't knonw what happened, can anyone help me?

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = ',测试项,信息,结果\r\n0,软件测试机型805,软件测试机型805,PASS\r\n1,软件当前版本1,软件当前版本1,FAIL\r\n2,软件测试机型805,软件测试机型805,PASS\r\n3,软件当前版本1,软件当前版本1,FAIL\r\n4,软件测试机型805,软件测试机型805,PASS\r\n5,软件当前版本1,软件当前版本1,FAIL\r\n'

buf = io.StringIO()
buf.write(s)

df = pd.read_csv(buf)
```

got error,  EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

老铁你拿去

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = ',测试项,信息,结果\r\n0,软件测试机型805,软件测试机型805,PASS\r\n1,软件当前版本1,软件当前版本1,FAIL\r\n2,软件测试机型805,软件测试机型805,PASS\r\n3,软件当前版本1,软件当前版本1,FAIL\r\n4,软件测试机型805,软件测试机型805,PASS\r\n5,软件当前版本1,软件当前版本1,FAIL\r\n'

buf = io.StringIO()
buf.write(s)
buf.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(buf)
``
```